# Bootstrap validator and proper form field validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

I am doing a bootstrap form validation, suppose a user has not entered value a in text, they are directly clicking submit button where we are displaying error in red color. After that user will enter value in text field means I have to hide error color.

I want to success green color in that particular text field with proper validation. Proper validation means suppose email means @ symbol iss there and mobile means 10 digits. All fields values field with proper validation after that only form can submit. How can I achieve this?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#btn-submit").click(function(){
   var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
   var email = $("#emailId").val();
   //console.log(email);
   if(firstName != ''){
    $("#fname").addClass("has-success has-feedback");
    $(".fname").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback");
   }else{
    $("#fname").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
     $(".fname").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback");
   }
   
   if(email != ''){
    $("#email").addClass("has-success has-feedback");
    $(".email").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback");
   }else{
    $("#email").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
     $(".email").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback");
   }
  
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal form: control states</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
  
   <div class="form-group" id="fname">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Click to focus...">
   <span class="fname"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
 
 <div class="form-group" id="email">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="emailId" type="email" placeholder="Click to focus...">
   <span class="email"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
 
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
     </div>
 
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My expected output (fields is not empty and proper validation).

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputSuccess">Input with success and glyphicon</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are adding the classes correctly but you are never removing the previous class.

Example: 
I leave the inputs blank and click submit... `has-error` class is added to `$("#fname")` element. If I then enter text into the firstname input and hit submit again... now the `$("#fname")` element has the `has-error` class and the `has-success` class.

You need to do something like `$("#fname").removeClass("has-error")` in each instance where you are adding the `has-success` class and vice versa.